# Java code prints message given in Exception even when conditions aren't true

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I am testing my user input in order to see if it is valid. If it is invalid it should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. However, the `IllegalArgumentException` in the first few lines of the `gameLogic` function gets thrown no matter what my input shall be. The result is that the program prints `"You're only permitted to enter Rock, Paper, Scissors or -1 in this game."` whatever my input is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class RockPaperScissors
{
    private static double mUserWinCount = 0;
    private static double mCpuWinCount = 0;
    private static double mUserLossCount = 0;
    private static double mCpuLossCount = 0; 
    private static double mDrawCount = 0;
    private static double mGameCount = 0;
    private static String mCpuInput;
    private static String mUserInput;


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

         try
         {
             gameLogic(cpuInput(),userInput());
         }
         catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
         {
             System.out.println(iae.getMessage());
         }


    }

    static String cpuInput()
    {
        Random random = new Random (System.currentTimeMillis());
        int RandomNumber=random.nextInt(3);
        if (RandomNumber == 0)
        mCpuInput = "Rock";
        else if (RandomNumber == 1)
        mCpuInput = "Paper";
        else
        mCpuInput = "Scissors";

        return mCpuInput;
    }

    static String userInput()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors, enter -1 in order to exit:- ");
        mUserInput = new Scanner(System.in).next();

        return mUserInput;

    }

    static void gameLogic(String cpuInput, String userInput)
    {
      if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || !userInput.equals("-1"))
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("You're only permitted to enter Rock, Paper, Scissors or -1 in this game.\n");
      }    

      if(userInput.equals("-1"))
      {
          score();
          System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("CPU entered "+cpuInput+", User entered "+userInput);  
      String [] args = new String[0];

      if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(cpuInput))
      {
          System.out.println("It's a draw!");
          mDrawCount++;
          mGameCount++;
      }
      if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
      {
         System.out.println("User wins!"); 
         mUserWinCount++; 
         mCpuLossCount++;
         mGameCount++;
      }  
      if(cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") || cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
      {
         System.out.println("CPU wins!"); 
         mCpuWinCount++; 
         mUserLossCount++;
         mGameCount++;
      }

      main(args);
    }



    static void score()
    { 
       if (mGameCount==0)
       {
          System.out.println("No games have been played..");
       }    
       else 
       {
           double userWinPercentage = (mUserWinCount / mGameCount) * 100;
           double userLossPercentage = (mUserLossCount / mGameCount) * 100;
           double cpuWinPercentage = (mCpuWinCount / mGameCount) * 100; 
           double cpuLossPercentage = (mCpuLossCount / mGameCount) * 100; 
           double drawPercentage = (mDrawCount/mGameCount) * 100;

           System.out.println("Number of Games Played- " + mGameCount);

           System.out.println("Number of Draws- "+ mDrawCount);
           System.out.println("Percentage of Draws "+ drawPercentage + "%");

           System.out.println("Number of Wins by User- " + mUserWinCount);
           System.out.println("User's Win Percentage- " + userWinPercentage + "%");
           System.out.println("Number of Losses by User- " + mCpuLossCount);
           System.out.println("User's Loss Percentage- " + userLossPercentage + "%");

           System.out.println("Number of Wins by CPU- " + mCpuWinCount);
           System.out.println("CPU's Win Percentage- " + cpuWinPercentage + "%");
           System.out.println("Number of Losses by CPU- " + mCpuLossCount);
           System.out.println("CPU's Loss Percentage- " + cpuLossPercentage + "%");
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If so please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")
```

This line is always true. We have three possbilities:

1. The word is neither "Rock" nor "Paper" (ignoring the case)
2. The word is "Rock"
3. The word is "Paper"

if a), both equalIgnoreCases will return false, then you "NOT" them with ! and you get TRUE || TRUE ( == TRUE, obviously )

if b) you get FALSE || TRUE ( == TRUE)

if c) you get TRUE || FALSE ( == TRUE)

Answer (score 4):

In this line

```
if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") || !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") || !userInput.equals("-1"))
```

use `&&`, not `||` <sup>†</sup>

```
if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && !userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && !userInput.equals("-1"))
```

You can use a form of truth table to understand why:

```
| Input      | A | B | C | D | || Result | && Result |
|------------+---+---+---+---+-----------|-----------|
| "Rock"     | F | T | T | T | T         | F         | 
| "Paper"    | T | F | T | T | T         | F         |
| "Scissors" | T | T | F | T | T         | F         |
| "-1"       | T | T | T | F | T         | F         |
| "foo"      | T | T | T | T | T         | T         |
```

<sup>†</sup> *However, from a design point of view, you probably want to restructure your code to ask the user to repeat the input if it is incorrect, rather than just terminating the game with an exception.*

Comment: How do I repeat the input part if it is incorrect? Would be grateful of your help..

Comment: @ShumsBadwal - that is a whole other question. SO is designed for one specific question per post. Once you have it working I suggest you post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and ask for help improving the code structure.

Comment: @ShumsBadwal I've created something that resembles a review in my answer; it repeats the input (hint: you should reuse the scanner).

Answer (score 0):

I'll show a refactored piece of code showing you an alternative method of handling the input and the main loop.

This code uses an explicit check on the input, using a `switch` over the input after making sure it is lowercase. Note that the check for the correct user input should be placed *outside* the game logic. Your game logic should be just that: the code to perform the game. What if you have two CPU players?

Besides that it contains a lot of coding hints, starting with NOTE: .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class RockPaperScissors {
    // NOTE: prefer integers instead of doubles for counts
    private static int mUserWinCount = 0;
    private static int mCpuWinCount = 0;
    // NOTE: avoid double state
    // isn't user loss always identical to cpu win count?
    private static int mUserLossCount = 0;
    private static int mCpuLossCount = 0;
    private static int mDrawCount = 0;
    private static int mGameCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // NOTE: always manage your resources
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            // NOTE: never use recursion unless you cannot avoid it
            // prefer while loop over calling main)
            while (true) {
                String userInput = userInput(scanner);
                if (userInput.equals("-1")) {
                    score();
                    // NOTE: prefer running out of main over calling exit
                    break;
                }

                // NOTE: bring back the amount of state ASAP!
                // just lowercase has less state, enums have even less
                if (!validChoice(userInput)) {
                    System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    String cpuInput = cpuInput();
                    gameLogic(cpuInput, userInput);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                    System.out.println(iae.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // NOTE: use explicit checks for user input
    static boolean validChoice(String userChoice) {
        switch (userChoice.toLowerCase()) {
        case "paper":
        case "scissors":
        case "rock":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

    static String cpuInput() {
        // NOTE: only define your variables in the scope where they are needed
        // this doesn't need to be a field
        String mCpuInput;

        // NOTE: prefer new SecureRandom() over Random if performance is not
        // essential
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int RandomNumber = random.nextInt(3);
        if (RandomNumber == 0)
            mCpuInput = "Rock";
        else if (RandomNumber == 1)
            mCpuInput = "Paper";
        else
            mCpuInput = "Scissors";

        return mCpuInput;
    }

    static String userInput(Scanner scanner) {
        String mUserInput;
        System.out
                .println("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors, enter -1 in order to exit:- ");
        mUserInput = scanner.next();
        return mUserInput;

    }

    static void gameLogic(String cpuInput, String userInput) {
        // NOTE: use logging instead for debug statements
        System.out.println("CPU entered " + cpuInput + ", User entered "
                + userInput);

        // NOTE: learn to detect code smell...
        // if you don't really need args you should not have to define it
        // String [] args = new String[0];

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(cpuInput)) {
            // NOTE: don't mix input/output with the actual game rules
            // return the outcome and then print instead (not fixed)
            System.out.println("It's a draw!");
            mDrawCount++;
            mGameCount++;
        }

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")
                && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")
                || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")
                && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")
                || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")
                && cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("User wins!");
            mUserWinCount++;
            mCpuLossCount++;
            mGameCount++;
        }
        if (cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")
                && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")
                || cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")
                && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")
                || cpuInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")
                && userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("CPU wins!");
            mCpuWinCount++;
            mUserLossCount++;
            mGameCount++;
        }

        // NOTE: avoid recursion
        // don't do this, if you do *document*
        // main(args);
    }

    static void score() {
        if (mGameCount == 0) {
            System.out.println("No games have been played..");
        } else {
            double userWinPercentage = (mUserWinCount / mGameCount) * 100;
            double userLossPercentage = (mUserLossCount / mGameCount) * 100;
            double cpuWinPercentage = (mCpuWinCount / mGameCount) * 100;
            double cpuLossPercentage = (mCpuLossCount / mGameCount) * 100;
            double drawPercentage = (mDrawCount / mGameCount) * 100;

            // NOTE: learn about printf when the time comes
            System.out.println("Number of Games Played- " + mGameCount);

            System.out.println("Number of Draws- " + mDrawCount);
            System.out.println("Percentage of Draws " + drawPercentage + "%");

            System.out.println("Number of Wins by User- " + mUserWinCount);
            System.out.println("User's Win Percentage- " + userWinPercentage
                    + "%");
            System.out.println("Number of Losses by User- " + mCpuLossCount);
            System.out.println("User's Loss Percentage- " + userLossPercentage
                    + "%");

            System.out.println("Number of Wins by CPU- " + mCpuWinCount);
            System.out.println("CPU's Win Percentage- " + cpuWinPercentage
                    + "%");
            System.out.println("Number of Losses by CPU- " + mCpuLossCount);
            System.out.println("CPU's Loss Percentage- " + cpuLossPercentage
                    + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: I haven't fixed everything, I explicitly didn't go into issues with regards to classes, public/private etc. as you probably are not at that chapter yet.

Comment: Well, I only needed one CPU and one user, I was half asleep while writing this code so I took this one quite lightly, but thanks anyways @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: No problem, but beware that code you produce while half asleep can come back to hound you. One Friday once cost me a Monday and a Tuesday to fix, would have been easier and better to start over.